# LLVM ArrayType with varying array size

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Hi, I'm currently working on LLVM IR and have a question.

I'm creating function using following code.

```
Function::Create(Ty, Linkage, "tile_load", mod);
```

In doing so, my function type Ty is represented as:

```
FunctionType *Ty = FunctionType::get(Builder.getVoidTy(), params, false);
```

One of my params is an array, which is currently pointed with int32*.

```
params.push_back(Type::getInt32PtrTy(mod->getContext()));
```

I want to change this part with ArrayType like `[10 * i32*]` but with varying array size.

I know that array type is defined like:

```
Type* I = IntegerType::getInt32Ty(mod->getContext());
auto num = 6;
ArrayType* arrayType = ArrayType::get(I, num);
```

But have no idea how to make an array type with size varying.

Does any body know how can it be done?

Thank you in advance.

jwlee

Comment: You can cast pointer types with `bitcast` instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are having fixed size. Array with "varying array size" is essentially a piece of memory. So, you'd need to use pointers for this. If at some point the size become compile-time constant you could bitcast to array type.